# Is $\|Ax\|/\|x\|$ the same for all $x\in V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a linear mapping $$A:V\to W$$ Is $\|A\|$ the same for all $x\in V$? Or is $\|A\|$ just the supremum of all possible values of $\|A\|/\|x\|$, which is a bounded set?

Comment: it is just the supremum. consider for example $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $W = \mathbb{R}$ with $A(x_1, x_2) := x_1$

Comment: @GitGud I suppose the OP means $||A||$ to be the norm of the operator $A$, tho I agree that the notation is sloppy

Comment: @mm-aops I don't understand anything. "Is $\|A\|=\|Ax\|/\|x\|$ the same for all $x\in V$?" What does it mean for an equality to be the same for all $x\in V$?

Comment: Why is no answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

The norm $A$ is $\|A\|:=\sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$. It is clear that $x \mapsto \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$ is not constant for every $A$.

E.g. : $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, then for $x = (1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$ we have $\|x\|_2=\|y\|_2= 1$ but $\|Ax\|_2 = 1 \neq \sqrt{2} = \|Ay\|_2$.

Answer (score 1):

The value $||A||$ is defined as the supremum of $$\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$$ over all $x\in V\setminus\{0\}$. Alternatively, it is the supremum of $$||Ax||$$ for all $x\in V$ for which $||x|| = 1$.

The value $$\frac{||Ax||}{||x||}$$ is not constant for all values of $x$ it can be for some matrices $A$, like orthogonal matrices and the zero matrix. In general, if $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ for which $|\lambda_1|\neq \lambda_2$ with eigenvectors $x_1,x_2$, then $$\frac{||Ax_1||}{||x_1||} = |\lambda_1|\neq|\lambda_2| \frac{||Ax_2||}{||x_2||}$$